# If $\;x\in\left[1,\infty \right)$, then $ x=\prod_{r=0}^\infty\left(1+\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^{2^r}\right)$

Tags: convergence-divergence, solution-verification, infinite-product

Let $\; t\in\mathbb{R} \;$ and let $\; \alpha,\beta\in(t,t+1) \;$ with $\; \alpha\not=\beta \;$ and consider $\;\displaystyle\frac{1-\alpha+\beta}{1+\alpha-\beta}$.

My goal was to  "simplify" $\; \displaystyle\frac{1-\alpha+\beta}{1+\alpha-\beta} \;$ as the product of terms. In the process of attempting this, I found that $$\frac{1-\alpha+\beta}{1+\alpha-\beta} = \left(1-\alpha+\beta\right)^2 \cdot\prod_{r=1}^\infty\left(1+\left(\alpha-\beta\right)^{2^r}\right)$$

Through a bit of algebraic reworking, I came to the more interesting conclusion that for any $x\in\left[1,\infty\right)$, $$x=\prod_{r=0}^\infty\left(1+\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^{\displaystyle2^r}\right)$$

I'm not sure whether my proof is airtight. I think that (if true) this is a really interesting property.  If anyone recognizes it or something similar, please let me know. I tried searching for it but came up with nothing. If anyone would check my proof and/or provide one of their own that would be splendid.

**My proof**:

---

$$\frac{1-\alpha+\beta}{1+\alpha-\beta}=\frac{\left(1-\alpha+\beta\right)^2}{\left(1+\alpha-\beta\right) \left(1-\alpha+\beta\right)}=\frac{\left(1-\alpha+\beta\right)^2}{1-\epsilon}$$

where

$$\epsilon=1-\left(1+\alpha-\beta\right)\left(1-\alpha+\beta\right)=\alpha^2+\beta^2-2\alpha\beta=\left(\alpha-\beta\right)^2$$ $$$$

Since $\; \alpha - \beta \in(-1,1)\text{,}\;$ we know that $1> \epsilon >0$.

\begin{align} \frac{\left(1-\alpha+\beta\right)^2}{1-\epsilon}&=\frac{\left(1-\alpha+\beta\right)^2\left(1+\epsilon\right)}{1-\epsilon^2} \\ \\ &= \frac{\left(1-\alpha+\beta\right)^2\left(1+\epsilon\right)\left(1+\epsilon^2\right)}{1-\epsilon^4} \\ \\ &= 
\frac{\left(1-\alpha+\beta\right)^2\left(1+\epsilon\right)\left(1+\epsilon^2\right)\left(1+\epsilon^4\right)}{1-\epsilon^8}  \\ \\ &= \cdots = \frac{\left(1-\alpha+\beta\right)^2\left(1+\epsilon\right)\left(1+\epsilon^2\right)\left(1+\epsilon^4\right)\cdots\left(1+\epsilon^{2^{n-1}}\right)\left(1+\epsilon^{2^n}\right)}{1-\epsilon^{2^{n+1}}}\end{align}

As $n\to\infty$, $\displaystyle\epsilon^{2^{n+1}}\to0$, and we have

\begin{align} \frac{1-\alpha+\beta}{1+\alpha-\beta}&=\left(1-\alpha+\beta\right)^2\left(1+\epsilon\right)\left(1+\epsilon^2\right)\left(1+\epsilon^4\right)\cdots \\ \\ &=\left(1-\alpha+\beta\right)^2 \cdot\prod_{r=0}^\infty\Bigr(1+\epsilon^{2^r}\Bigr) \\ \\
&=\left(1-\alpha+\beta\right)^2 \cdot\prod_{r=0}^\infty \Bigr(1+\left(\left(\alpha-\beta\right)^2\right)^{2^r}\Bigr) \\ \\
&= \left(1-\alpha+\beta\right)^2 \cdot\prod_{r=1}^\infty \Bigr(1+ \left(\alpha-\beta\right)^{2^r}\Bigr)
\end{align}
$$$$
Dividing both sides of the equation above by $\left(1-\alpha+\beta\right)^2 \text{,}\;$ (a nonzero term), we arrive at

$$\frac{1}{\left(1+\alpha-\beta\right)\left(1-\alpha+\beta\right)} = \frac{1}{\left(1+(\alpha-\beta)\right)\left(1-(\alpha-\beta)\right)} = \prod_{r=1}^\infty \Bigr(1+ \left(\alpha-\beta\right)^{2^r}\Bigr)$$ $$$$

$\alpha - \beta\;$ is an arbitrary value in $\left(-1,1\right) \text{,} \;$ so for any $\gamma\in \left(-1,1\right)$, we have

$$\frac{1}{\left(1+\gamma\right)\left(1-\gamma\right)} = \frac{1}{1-\gamma^2} = \prod_{r=1}^\infty \Bigr(1+ \gamma^{2^r}\Bigr) $$ $$$$

Now let $\;x\in\mathbb{R}\;$ such that $\; x=\frac{1}{1-\gamma^2} \;$ with $\gamma \in \left(-1,1\right)\text{.}\;$ Then $$x=\frac{1}{1-\gamma^2}\iff \gamma=\pm \sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x}}$$ $$$$

We can see here that $\; x \;$ is necessarily an element of $\;\left[1,\infty\right)\;$because $\; x\in\left(-\infty,0\right)\Longrightarrow \gamma>1\;$ (a contradiction), and $\; x\in\left[0,1\right)\Longrightarrow \gamma\not\in\mathbb{R}\;$ (a contradiction). Note that $\; \frac{x-1}{x}\geq 0 \;$ for any $\;x\in\left[1,\infty\right)$.

Thus, if $\; x\in\left[1,\infty\right)\text{,}\;$ then $$x=\prod_{r=1}^\infty\left(1+\left(\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x}}\right)^{\displaystyle2^r}\right)=\prod_{r=0}^\infty\left(1+\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^{\displaystyle2^r}\right)$$

---

Example ($x=7$): [Wolfram Alpha Example 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product%20of%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A1%2B%28%287-1%29%2F7%29%5E%282%5Ek%29%2F%2F%5D%20from%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3Ak%2F%2F%5D%3D%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A0%2F%2F%5D%20to%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3Ainfinity%2F%2F%5D)

Answer (score 3):

We have a telescoping product,$$\prod_{r\ge0}\left(1+y^{2^r}\right)=\prod_{r\ge0}\frac{1-y^{2^{r+1}}}{1-y^{2^r}}=\frac{1}{1-y}$$for $|y|<1$. Now take $y=1-\frac1x$ for $x\ge1$.